# How to assign value from cypress response to global variable

Tags: cypress, response, variable-assignment, var, assign

```
export function createDashboardGroup(dashboardGroupName: string): string {
    let preferredOrgId = '';
    var ID = '' // it will be string;

cy.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: getRequestUrl('/v2/user/_/preferences'),
})
.then((res) => {
    preferredOrgId = res.body.sf_preferredOrg;
    cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: getRequestUrl(`/v2/dashboardgroup?organizationId=${preferredOrgId}`),
        body: {
            name: dashboardGroupName,
        },
    })
.then((dashboardRes) => {
        ID = dashboardRes.body.id;
    })
});
return ID;
}
```

Once I try to get the value of `ID` it returns an empty value. I was searching around, and could not find a solution. How I can get the value of the response and assign it to the global `ID` var and return it?

Answer (score 5):

Please set it in an alias

```js
.then((dashboardRes) => {
  cy.wrap(dashboardRes.body.id).as('id')
})
```

Access it later via

```js
cy.get('@id').then(id => {

})
```

Read this page to get background [Variables and Aliases](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases)

Answer (score 0):

You could store the variable as a global Cypress variable. In your last `.then()` block...

```js
.then((dashboardRes) => {
  Cypress.env('dashboardRes', dashboardRes)
})
.then(() => {
  // test what you need with `Cypress.env('dashboardRes')`;
});
```

You could then reference it in your test by calling `Cypress.env('dashboardRes');`

Comment: I thought of that, but `Cypress.env('dashboardRes')` is synchronous so this won't work if use in the same test. You would still need a `.then()`.

Comment: Yep, I was thinking that but didn't add it. I'll put it in my answer.

Comment: @agoff I was planning to create an API call in a separate file, and save that response. In my tests I need that response, but I was planning to store all API call in separate folder. If I will use `.then` in the test file will it get cypress env var?

Comment: If you call whatever function would save a value in a Cypress environment variable, then you should be able to reference that environment variable later in your test. I'm not sure I 100% understand what you are describing, but I think the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was not necessarily a global variable, but going off of this https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-tips-and-tricks/#wait-for-data

I created an object, then on the response, set a variable to the object. Then in the test, wrap the object, do `.then()` and then you have access to it.

Not saying this is the best way at all but it worked for my use case and may be helpful to someone

```
// commands.js
let data = {}
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('visit', (originalFn, url, options) => {
  cy.intercept(/endpoint', (req) => {
    req.continue((res) => {
      data.info = res.body.info
    })
  })
})
export { data }

/// ----- in test file ------ ////

import { data } from '../support/commands'

it('test', () => {
  cy.wrap(data).then((data) => {
    console.log(data.info) // here you have access to it
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to set a variable is to make use of the browser's `window` object and assigning the value to the `sessionStorage`

snippet -

```
.then((dashboardRes) => {
        window.sessionStorage.setItem(ID, dashboardRes.body.id);
    })
});
```

It can be accessed within the test file (even from another test case) as follows -

```
let ID = window.sessionStorage.getItem('ID');
```

However, please note that this is an anti-pattern, making one test rely on the output of another. It is described in the [Cypress Best Practices](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Having-Tests-Rely-On-The-State-Of-Previous-Tests) as well.